# ReportLineagetoAtlas in Nifi not maintaing state of all nodes in Nifi Cluster

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-atlas

We have a NiFi cluster of 3 nodes having 100 flows deployed. We have configured a task ReportLineageToAtlas in NiFi which is syncing lineage information of flows to Apache Atlas.

From the past few days it has stopped publishing lineage to Atlas.

Few Observations :

```
This task is not maintaining state for all the nodes in the cluster.Its maintaing consistently only for two nodes.
No other error reported in NiFi logs.
```

Please can someone suggests how to sync states as currently in Nifi cluster all nodes are connected.